# Disable blackfire module temporary

Tags: php, xdebug, blackfire

I've sucessfully installed the blackfire agent, cli tool and probe and it works fine. I've disabled the xdebug module while profiling with bf.

Now I want to use xdebug as I did before, but xdebug does not work, it just won't enter a debugging session. No breakpoint and not even `xdebug_break` work. A quote from the producers website says:

> Known incompatibilities
>
> Please note that PHP compiled with debug are not supported and that
>   the Probe may conflict with XDebug or XHProf; disable those extensions
>   when enabling the Probe.

Is there a way to disable the blackfire agent **WITHOUT** uninstalling the whole blackfire tool chain ? Moving the file `/etc/php5/conf.d/90-blackfire.ini` to a backup location didn't work.

**Update**
What works is uninstalling the php agent `sudo apt-get remove blackfire-php`. But I'm pretty sure there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply edit the file `/etc/php5/conf.d/90-blackfire.ini` and comment the following line `extension=blackfire.so`. Don't forget to restart apache2 or php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

You can run the next command to turn off PHP extensions/modules:

```
$ sudo phpdismod blackfire
```

The opposite of this command is:

```
$ sudo phpenmod blackfire
```

To apply all changes you must restart your service. Example:

```
$ sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```